# Jquery assigning option first-child text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I replaced the first child option with custom text to override all 3 drop downs. When I then select the category the subcategory changes to default text "-------". I would like to retain the assigned text on all first-child options no matter the selection.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select[name=category]").on("change", function() {
                $("select[name='category'] > option:first-child").text('Category');
                $("select[name='subcategory'] > option:first-child").text('Subcategory');
                $("select[name='name'] > option:first-child").text('Recipe');
                if($(this).val() == "") { 
                    $("select[name=subcategory]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $("select[name=name]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');    
                } else {
                    $("select[name=subcategory]").removeAttr("disabled");
                    if($("select[name=subcategory]").val() == "") { 
                        $("select[name=name]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    } else {
                        $("select[name=name]").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                }
            }).trigger('change');

            $("select[name=subcategory]").on("change", function() {
                if($(this).val() == "") { 
                    $("select[name=name]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                } else {
                    $("select[name=name]").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }).trigger('change');
        });
    </script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="category">
        <option value="">----------</option>
        <option value="suv">suv</option>
        <option value="sedan">sedan</option>
    </select>
        <select name="subcategory">
        <option value="">----------</option>
        <option value="honda">honda</option>
        <option value="toyota">toyota</option>
    </select>
        <select name="name">
        <option value="">----------</option>
        <option value="200x">200x</option>
        <option value="400x">400x</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the html code to your questions? Thank you.

Comment: @TOH19 yes done